# How to use a printer on a Windows PC from Loki

Tags: networking, printer

I have just installed eOS Loki on a PC that is on a LAN with a Windows 10 PC.
I can see shared folders on the Win PC from eOS, but haven't been able to work out how to print to the printer that is connected to the Win PC from eOS. I've used CUPS to define a printer, and have tried Internet Printing Protocol (http or https), but then I'm guessing what to put in the IP address field. I'm fairly sure the Win PC has IP address 192.168.0.3 (it pings ok). I've tried "http://192.168.0.3:631/ipp/" but get "printer not connected". Can anybody suggest what settings I need?

Comment: that seem more like an ubuntu issue - and more likely to get assistance on askubuntu

Comment: You should make sure you share the printer on your Windows PC, after that you should be able to browser and find it as a network printer in CUPS.

Comment: The printer is shared in Windows, but doesn't seem to show in CUPS. I'm wondering whether I need to change the workgroup name. Can anybody tell me where it is defined in eOS?

Comment: I think cipricus is right. Probably I should be using ubuntu.